# How to decode an array in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

Hi I get response from server like so:

```
[
    {
        "success": {
            "/lights/1/state/on": true
        }
    }
]
```

and I'd like to encode it how to do it ? I try something like this but it didn't work:

```
struct ResponseModel: Decodable {
    
    var response: [ResponseDataModel]

    struct ResponseDataModel: Decodable {
        var status: [String: String]
    }
}

let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseModel.self, from: data)
                        
print(decodedResponse)
```

Comment: You mean decode it

Comment: One of the decoding rules is that property names must match the JSON keys. There is no key `response` and no key `status` in the JSON. Add a `do - catch` block and print the error. DecodingErrors are very descriptive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean decode it. The property is not `response` should be `success`, and you are receiving an array not a dictionary. Note also your dictionary value type should be a `Bool` not a `String`:

```
let json = """
[
    {
        "success": {
            "/lights/1/state/on": true
        }
    }
]
"""
```

---

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    var success: [String: Bool]
}
```

---

```
let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode([Response].self, from: Data(json.utf8))
if let firstElement = decodedResponse.first {
    print(firstElement) // "Response(success: ["/lights/1/state/on": true])\n"
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was so easy and I forgot about it lol